# Why I can't change the style of list in depth-3

Tags: html, css

Maybe The title is confusing for you, but it exactly the title said, I try to change the `list-style-type` to have a different type based on condition, but whenever I try to go to depth-3 it failed to change the style

```css
/* success to Change*/

#paham-post-content ul li{
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    list-style-type: disc;
    color: green;
}

#paham-post-content ul li > ul li{
    list-style-type: circle;
    color: green;
}

#paham-post-content ul li > ol li{
    list-style-type: decimal;
    color: green;
}

/* Failed to Change*/

#paham-post-content ul li > ul li > ul li{
    list-style-type: square;
    color: red;
}

#paham-post-content ul li > ul li > ol li{
    list-style-type: decimal;
    color: red;
}

#paham-post-content ul li > ol li > ul li{
    list-style-type: square;
    color: red;
}

#paham-post-content ul li > ol li > ol li{
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
    color: red;
}


/* success to Change*/

#paham-post-content ol li{
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    list-style-type: decimal;
    color: green;
}

#paham-post-content ol li > ul li{
    list-style-type: disc;
    color: green;
}

#paham-post-content ol li > ol li{
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
    color: green;
}

/* Failed to Change*/

#paham-post-content ol li > ul li > ul li{
    list-style-type: square;
    color: red;
}

#paham-post-content ol li > ul li > ol li{
    list-style-type: decimal;
    color: red;
}

#paham-post-content ol li > ol li > ul li{
    list-style-type: square;
    color: red;
}

#paham-post-content ol li > ol li > ol li{
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body id="paham-post-content">

<h1>ul li</h1>

<ul>
 <li>
     ul li
    </li>
    
 <li>
     <p>ul li</p>
        <ul>
         <li>
             ul li ul li
            </li>
         <li>
             ul li ul li
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    
 <li>
     <p>ul li</p>
        <ol>
         <li>
             ul li ol li
            </li>
         <li>
             ul li ol li
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    
 <li>
     <p>ul li</p>
        <ul>
         <li>
             ul li ul li
            </li>
            <ul>
              <li>
                ul li ul li ul li
              </li>
              <li>
                ul li ul li ul li
              </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>

        <ul>
         <li>
             ul li ul li
            </li>
            <ol>
              <li>
                ul li ul li ol li
              </li>
              <li>
                ul li ul li ol li
              </li>
            </ol>
        </ul>

        <ol>
         <li>
             ul li ol li
            </li>
            <ul>
              <li>
                ul li ol li ul li
              </li>
              <li>
                ul li ol li ul li
              </li>
            </ul>
        </ol>


        <ol>
         <li>
             ul li ol li
            </li>
            <ol>
              <li>
                ul li ol li ol li
              </li>
              <li>
                ul li ol li ol li
              </li>
            </ol>
        </ol>

 </li>
</ul>


<h1>ol li</h1>

<ol>
 <li>
     ol li
    </li>
    
 <li>
     <p>ol li</p>
        <ul>
         <li>
             ol li ul li
            </li>
         <li>
             ol li ul li
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    
 <li>
     <p>ol li</p>
        <ol>
         <li>
             ol li ol li
            </li>
         <li>
             ol li ol li
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    
 <li>
     <p>ol li</p>
        <ul>
         <li>
             ol li ul li
            </li>
            <ul>
              <li>
                ol li ul li ul li
              </li>
              <li>
                ol li ul li ul li
              </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>

        <ul>
         <li>
             ol li ul li
            </li>
            <ol>
              <li>
                ol li ul li ol li
              </li>
              <li>
                ol li ul li ol li
              </li>
            </ol>
        </ul>

        <ol>
         <li>
             ol li ol li
            </li>
            <ul>
              <li>
                ol li ol li ul li
              </li>
              <li>
                ol li ol li ul li
              </li>
            </ul>
        </ol>


        <ol>
         <li>
             ol li ol li
            </li>
            <ol>
              <li>
                ol li ol li ol li
              </li>
              <li>
                ol li ol li ol li
              </li>
            </ol>
        </ol>

 </li>
</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, there is no `color: red` applied in the depth-3, can someone help me, why this behaviour occur and how to solve it? can we achieve it without **Make a New Class**?

Comment: Why not using `classes` to avoid that messy CSS

Comment: @Awais Thank you for your response, its because I must overide the style in wordpress and elementor text editor since I can't insert class in there, I must defined it like that

Comment: It's a little confusing but it appears that, in some cases, your structure does not match the selectors you are using.

Comment: @RakishFrisky its little bit confusing as @paulie mention that the structure is confusing and different so you need a lot more selector to achieve your goal, and in current scenario you are selecting wrong selector, Correct selector is `#paham-post-content > ul >li > ul > ul > li {    list-style-type: circle;    color: red;}` and as you can see the structure is different so you need separate sector for next target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements were in the wrong place, they should be inside the LI as per your css styling. I have fixed few so that it's clear.

```css
/* success to Change*/

#paham-post-content ul li {
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top: 1vh;
  list-style-type: disc;
  color: green;
}

#paham-post-content ul li>ul li {
  list-style-type: circle;
  color: green;
}

#paham-post-content ul li>ol li {
  list-style-type: decimal;
  color: green;
}


/* Failed to Change*/

#paham-post-content ul li>ul li>ul li {
  list-style-type: square;
  color: red;
}

#paham-post-content ul li>ul li>ol li {
  list-style-type: decimal;
  color: red;
}

#paham-post-content ul li>ol li>ul li {
  list-style-type: square;
  color: red;
}

#paham-post-content ul li>ol li>ol li {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
  color: red;
}


/* success to Change*/

#paham-post-content ol li {
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top: 1vh;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  color: green;
}

#paham-post-content ol li>ul li {
  list-style-type: disc;
  color: green;
}

#paham-post-content ol li>ol li {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
  color: green;
}


/* Failed to Change*/

#paham-post-content ol li>ul li>ul li {
  list-style-type: square;
  color: red;
}

#paham-post-content ol li>ul li>ol li {
  list-style-type: decimal;
  color: red;
}

#paham-post-content ol li>ol li>ul li {
  list-style-type: square;
  color: red;
}

#paham-post-content ol li>ol li>ol li {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body id="paham-post-content">

  <h1>ul li</h1>

  <ul>
    <li>
      ul li
    </li>

    <li>
      <p>ul li</p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          ul li ul li
        </li>
        <li>
          ul li ul li
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <p>ul li</p>
      <ol>
        <li>
          ul li ol li
        </li>
        <li>
          ul li ol li
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>

    <li>
      <p>ul li</p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          ul li ul li
          <!--  This ul below should be inside the li not outside  -->
          <ul>
            <li>
              ul li ul li ul li
            </li>
            <li>
              ul li ul li ul li
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>

      <ul>
        <li>
          ul li ul li
          <ol>
            <li>
              ul li ul li ol li
            </li>
            <li>
              ul li ul li ol li
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>

      </ul>

      <ol>
        <li>
          ul li ol li
        </li>
        <ul>
          <li>
            ul li ol li ul li
          </li>
          <li>
            ul li ol li ul li
          </li>
        </ul>
      </ol>


      <ol>
        <li>
          ul li ol li
        </li>
        <ol>
          <li>
            ul li ol li ol li
          </li>
          <li>
            ul li ol li ol li
          </li>
        </ol>
      </ol>

    </li>
  </ul>


  <h1>ol li</h1>

  <ol>
    <li>
      ol li
    </li>

    <li>
      <p>ol li</p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          ol li ul li
        </li>
        <li>
          ol li ul li
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <p>ol li</p>
      <ol>
        <li>
          ol li ol li
        </li>
        <li>
          ol li ol li
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>

    <li>
      <p>ol li</p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          ol li ul li
        </li>
        <ul>
          <li>
            ol li ul li ul li
          </li>
          <li>
            ol li ul li ul li
          </li>
        </ul>
      </ul>

      <ul>
        <li>
          ol li ul li
        </li>
        <ol>
          <li>
            ol li ul li ol li
          </li>
          <li>
            ol li ul li ol li
          </li>
        </ol>
      </ul>

      <ol>
        <li>
          ol li ol li
        </li>
        <ul>
          <li>
            ol li ol li ul li
          </li>
          <li>
            ol li ol li ul li
          </li>
        </ul>
      </ol>


      <ol>
        <li>
          ol li ol li
        </li>
        <ol>
          <li>
            ol li ol li ol li
          </li>
          <li>
            ol li ol li ol li
          </li>
        </ol>
      </ol>

    </li>
  </ol>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, its my fault, there is a miss placed in the architecture, thank you for your answer, it help me a lot, at first I think I mustn't use it like yours, but instead your code is right

Comment: Yes, The child lists should always be inside the li. Glad I helped.